# Bootcamp is unable to boot Windows 8.1

Tags: macos, boot, windows-8.1, boot-camp, parallels

Ok I've tried the most tactics to this but i am still stuck.
I am unable to boot into windows on my Macbook pro 2012. I have been using Parallels lately and for the first time it read that it is unable to run startup repair. It told me to look in the SrtTrail.txt, which checks the boot logs. When i skimmed through it, using Finder in OSX, i found this error.

### Root cause found:

Boot critical file c:\windows\system32\drivers\prl_strg.sys is corrupt.

Repair action: File repair
Result: Failed. Error code =  0x2
Time taken = 7031 ms

Repair action: System files integrity check and repair
Result: Failed. Error code =  0x490
Time taken = 1131625 ms

---

I looked up the prl_strg.sys file and apparently its a file that comes from Parallels uses to boot. This is what I've tried so far.

1. Rebooted my computer
2. Attempted full restores, no luck
3. Attempted Startup Repair, No luck
4. Attempted to Boot natively and attempted above steps, no luck